# Encoding Error With pandas read_CSV file context

Tags: pandas, dataframe, encoding

I was trying import 15 CSV files using pandas and and glob I have to create one combine data frame which is
used to manipulated my data but I was importing the data that time I getting the error and it was is that
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

I was try difference encoding Codec which pandas documentation was already mentions but it was not working et the end. I need the correct encoding Codec for my code.

```
###### Import Module
import os

import pandas as pd

import glob


csv_files = glob.glob('PATH')

###### Create an empty dataframe to store the combined data
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()

###### Loop through each CSV file and append its contents to the combined dataframe
for csv_file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    df_LV_StoreCard = pd.concat([combined_df, df])

###### Print the combined dataframe
print(df_LV_StoreCard)
```

Comment: If it's coming from files stored in a Windows system maybe try `encoding='cp1252'` instead?

Comment: I have try this but it was also not working.

Comment: It might be worth manually looking at the file that's tripping the code up to see if it has any unusual/unexpected characters in it?

Comment: Check if there is a BOM at the start of the file. It is illegal, but Microsoft sofware likes to write BOMs at the start of UTF-8 files.